# WSDL is not generated

Tags: spring, web-services, wsdl, cxf, maven-plugin

I have added below plugin into `pom.xml` but I dont know where the wsdl is generated or may be the wsdl is not generated. I do not get any error while doing clean & install

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process-classes</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <configuration>
                <className>com.alu.usddomega.ws.facade.customeroffer.CustomerOfferFacadeImpl</className>
                <outputFile>${basedir}/src/main/java/wsdl/CusttomerOffer.wsdl</outputFile>
                <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <genServer>false</genServer>
                <targetNamespace>http://customeroffer.manage.ws.usddomega.alu.com/</targetNamespace>
                <attachWsdl>true</attachWsdl>
                <serviceName>getCustomerOffer</serviceName>
                <databinding>ManageCustomerOffer</databinding>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>java2ws</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL should be at:

`<outputFile>${basedir}/src/main/java/wsdl/CusttomerOffer.wsdl</outputFile>`

Comment: I thought of same but it is not there.

Comment: Have you tried running Maven with the -X argument to see what it prints when the CXF plugin is run ?